# Installing 'tensorflow-gpu' tries to download every version

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am following a youtube video on how to do audio classification in Tensorflow. During the video, I am asked to download these dependencies

```
pip install tensorflow tensorflow-gpu tensorflow-io matplotlib
```

As good practice, I create a `venv` and let my Jupyter notebook use that. I noticed though that it attempts to download every version of `tensorflow-gpu` which can get quite large

```
(venv) c:\users\myuser\myproject>pip install tensorflow tensorflow-gpu tensorflow-io matplotlib
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.11.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (1.9 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.10.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (455.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 455.9 MB 106 kB/s
Collecting tensorflow-io
  Downloading tensorflow_io-0.28.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (22.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 22.9 MB 6.4 MB/s
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-3.6.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (7.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.2 MB 2.2 MB/s
Collecting tensorflow-intel==2.11.0
  Downloading tensorflow_intel-2.11.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (266.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 266.3 MB 3.3 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\myuser\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.11.0->tensorflow) (57.4.0)
Collecting packaging
  Downloading packaging-22.0-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 42 kB 3.2 MB/s
Collecting protobuf<3.20,>=3.9.2
  Using cached protobuf-3.19.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (895 kB)
Collecting wrapt>=1.11.0
  Using cached wrapt-1.14.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (35 kB)
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0
  Downloading termcolor-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
Collecting flatbuffers>=2.0
  Downloading flatbuffers-22.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting gast<=0.4.0,>=0.2.1
  Downloading gast-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
Collecting absl-py>=1.0.0
  Using cached absl_py-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (124 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem>=0.23.1
  Downloading tensorflow_io_gcs_filesystem-0.28.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.1
  Downloading google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 57 kB ...
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.6
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting tensorboard<2.12,>=2.11
  Downloading tensorboard-2.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.0 MB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting astunparse>=1.6.0
  Downloading astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting keras<2.12,>=2.11.0
  Downloading keras-2.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.7 MB 3.2 MB/s
Collecting libclang>=13.0.0
  Downloading libclang-14.0.6-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (14.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.2 MB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting opt-einsum>=2.3.2
  Downloading opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 65 kB 1.8 MB/s
Collecting h5py>=2.9.0
  Downloading h5py-3.7.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.6 MB 6.8 MB/s
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.12,>=2.11.0
  Downloading tensorflow_estimator-2.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (439 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 439 kB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting six>=1.12.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting grpcio<2.0,>=1.24.3
  Downloading grpcio-1.51.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (3.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.7 MB 6.8 MB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.20
  Downloading numpy-1.23.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (14.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.7 MB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.10.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (455.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 455.9 MB 3.2 MB/s
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.9.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (444.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 444.1 MB 60 kB/s
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.9.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (444.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 444.1 MB 10 kB/s
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.9.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (444.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 444.0 MB 12 kB/s
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.9.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (444.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 444.0 MB 3.3 MB/s
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.8.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (438.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 438.4 MB 84 kB/s
Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.1.1
  Downloading Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 42 kB 3.2 MB/s
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.8.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (438.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 438.4 MB 4.5 kB/s
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.8.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (438.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 438.3 MB 17 kB/s
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.8.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (438.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 438.3 MB 6.4 MB/s
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.8.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (438.0 MB)

ERROR: Operation cancelled by user
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
```

Why does it need to download every single Tensorflow GPU version?

Comment: Youtube videos are not generally a good source of ML knowledge, it does not make sense to install both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu, it is one or the other, mutually exclusive.

Comment: Try to find more recent sources since this seems outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as @Dr. Snoopy mentioned in his comment you need not to install both mode of tensorflow(for CPU) or tensorflow-gpu(for GPU). You can install either of them as below:

```
!pip install tensorflow-io tensorflow-gpu==2.10 matplotlib #Tensorflow 2.11 is not supported for native-Windows
```

or

```
!pip install tensorflow-io tensorflow matplotlib
```